# Convert date time to day and time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a variable in a df that looks like this

```
Datetime
10/27/2020 2:28:28 PM
8/2/2020   3:30:18 AM
6/15/2020  5:38:19 PM
```

How can I change it to this using python?

```
Date            Time
10/27/2020      14:28:28
8/2/2020        3:30:18
6/15/2020       17:38:19
```

I understand how to separate date and time, but unsure of how to convert it to 24 hour time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert a scalar, array-like, Series or DataFrame/dict-like to a pandas datetime object. Then, you can use the accessor object for datetimelike properties of the Series values (`Series.dt()`) to obtain the time, that will be already in the desired format.

You can also use [dt.strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to format the output string which supports the same string format as the python standard library.

```py
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime)

df['Date'] = df.Datetime.dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
df['Time'] = df.Datetime.dt.time

print(df)
```

```py
             Datetime        Date      Time
0 2020-10-27 14:28:28  10/27/2020  14:28:28
1 2020-08-02 03:30:18  08/02/2020  03:30:18
2 2020-06-15 17:38:19  06/15/2020  17:38:19
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is source you want:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
dt = parse("10/27/2020 2:28:28")
print(dt)
# 2020-10-27 02:28:28
# Create Date
date=f"{str(dt.year)}/{str(dt.month)}/{str(dt.day)}"
# Create Time
time=f"{str(dt.hour)}:{str(dt.minute)}:{str(dt.second)}"
```

Comment: That’s the idea, yes. But how can I do it with my data instead of using datetime.now()? Sorry I’m a python beginner.

Comment: See my edited code

Comment: Thank you, instead of parsing a specific datetime, how can I parse the entire column?

Comment: is entire a list? Like ```["10/27/2020 2:28:28","8/2/2020 3:30:18","6/15/2020 5:38:19" ] or else?```